# How to change a text into a math operator?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

For example, I write `\max_{\forall n}`, this results in `\forall n` to be underneath `\max`.

But `\textsf{max}` is so much cuter than `\max`.

I want to write `\textsf{max}_{\forall n}` and preserve the appearance as before.

But I am thrown an error:

> `\textsf{max}` is not a math operator.

Is there anyway of changing `\textsf{max}` into a math operator?

Answer (score 4):

In `\displaystyle`, the subscript goes under the operator.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\sfmax}{\mathsf{max}}
\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}
$y = \sfmax_{\forall n} A_n$

$\displaystyle y = \sfmax_{\forall n} A_n$

$\scriptstyle y = \sfmax_{\forall n} A_n$
\end{document}
```

[image]